# "Expanding Mode" Analogue to Pandas "expanding_mean"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe indexed by both "project_id" and "date". Think of this as time series data for each project. For each project, I want to create a new time series containing the modes of the series of previous values in time. I was able to easily do this for the mean, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'project_id':[1,1,2,3,3,3],
              'date':      [0,1,0,0,1,2],
              'value':     [5,6,7,8,9,12]})
df.set_index('project_id','date',inplace=True)
just_mean = df.groupby(level="project_id",sort=False)['value'].transform(pd.expanding_mean)
mean_df = df.copy()
mean_df['value'] = just_mean
```

However, it doesn't seem like Pandas has an equivalent function for mode (or lots of other functions one might want to consider on time varying series). Is there an efficient way using numpy to define a function that will do this? Right now I have the following, which relies on a Python for loop and is inefficient:

```
def func(x):
    new_series = x.copy()
    sorted_counts = np.ones(len(x.unique()),dtype=[('x',int),('y',int)])
    sorted_counts['x'] *= -1
    sorted_counts['y'] *= -1
    for i,val in enumerate(new_series.values.astype(int)):
        valIdx = np.argwhere(sorted_counts['x'] == val)
        if valIdx:
            sorted_counts['y'][valIdx] += 1
        else:
            sorted_counts[0] = (val,1)
        sorted_counts.sort(order='y')
        new_series.iloc[i] = sorted_counts['x'][-1]
    return new_series

mode = self.df.groupby(level='project_id',sort=False)['value'].transform(func)
mode_df = self.df.copy()
mode_df['value']=mode
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner (after importing `mode` from scipy):

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import mode

df.groupby(level='project_id').apply(
           lambda x: pd.expanding_apply( x, lambda y: mode(y)[0][0] ) )

            date  value
project_id             
1              0      5
1              0      5
2              0      7
3              0      8
3              0      8
3              0      8
```

And here's a more gradual explanation.  First, note that you could write your expanding mean like this.

```
df.groupby(level='project_id').apply( pd.expanding_mean )
```

But you could also do it like this.

```
df.groupby(level='project_id').apply( lambda x: pd.expanding_apply(x,np.mean) )
```

That almost gets us to the answer, but mode is a little trickier than mean in that it returns a tuple of arrays rather than a plain old number like mean.  So the extra code you see above (`lambda` and `[0][0]`) is just there to convert it to a plain number as required by `expanding_apply`.

Comment: Cool thanks- somehow I couldn't find that expanding_apply function anywhere

Comment: Sure, no problem.  It's basically the same idea as `rolling_apply` and similarly the trick is sometimes getting the syntax right which is not always easy.

Comment: Interestingly enough, even though my code has that straight up Python for-loop, it runs approximately twice as fast as the pandas built-in one-liner. I bet it recalculates the mode for each new row or lacks some similar optimization because 'expanding_apply' can't know ahead of time what function it's going to expand

Comment: I dunno for sure, but your explanation makes sense.  There's really no way for expanding_apply to optimize for generic functions in the way that rolling_mean can for a mean or your custom version can for mode.